# how to add button value explicitly to request in jsp javascript

Tags: javascript, struts2

i am trying to pass button value from jsp to servlet in struts framework while form is being disabled on click the search button..i am able to get all the value except search button value. its showing null for search button Please suggest how to handle it   :)  ??

Reply please

Comment: what exactly you doing are you submitting the form or what is your use case.without all this information hard to tell

Comment: to perform the search operation by avoid the same data double submission

Comment: if you want double submission problem use http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/token-session-interceptor.html or http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/token-interceptor.html

Answer (score 0):

The browser will only send the value of the button if the user clicked that button when submitting the form.  If you need the value on the server regardless of whether the user clicked the button, try putting it in a `hidden` field instead.